# How come inline video src media queries aren't working?

Tags: html, css, video

I have two videos for a webpage I created recently but the inline media queries aren't working.

The player is just pulling the first video in the list of sources.

Here is my code:

```
        <video class="intro-video" controls poster="lineandgrid-video-intro-cover.gif">
            <source media="(max-width: 750px)" src="lineandgrid-introduction-video-mobile.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            <source media="(min-width: 751px)" src="lineandgrid-introduction-video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? You can view the live webpage here: https://lineandgrid.ca/video/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Media queries are generally only supported for <picture> elements.

> Attributes: Media:
> Media query of the resource's intended media; **this should be used only in a <picture> element.**

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/source:

> Chrome does not support inline media queries on the source tag within
> videotag. [...] Worse, plain media queries will not stop multiple
> videos from loading, which effectively doubles your data, so it
> requires a JS solution.

Source: https://blog.greggant.com/posts/2019/08/02/responsive-videos-javascript-solution-video-source-tag.html

The proposed JS solution, if the original blog post becomes unavailable: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/fuzzywalrus/8abdd088e3fb6a73fd5d980f7bab0118/raw/9922cce9c4c040164f383671070e588c2adff944/responsivevideo.js

---

*Original answer:*

> Apparently, support for inline media queries has been removed:
>
> [Chrome not respecting video source inline media queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25907930/chrome-not-respecting-video-source-inline-media-queries)

Comment: That's from 6 years ago, and it works for images on my website, just not for the video.

Comment: https://blog.greggant.com/posts/2019/08/02/responsive-videos-javascript-solution-video-source-tag.html

Comment: Noooo, not Javascript. This is such a basic thing, why doesn't Chrome support it... so ridiculous. If you post your previous answer as a legitimate answer I'll mark it as correct. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome! I've added some more information to my original answer. Btw, my Firefox also does not seem to support this feature... Too bad!